# Cannot Get Index.html File Changes to be Read (Apache 2.4)

Tags: apache, web, server

So I am at my wits end with this problem of trying to configure a simple Apache Web Server for one of my assignments. For some reason my changes to index.html are no longer being read, even though I got it to change previously.

I had this problem previously, where I would change index.html and it would still show the default "It works!" message. It ended up that, because my file extensions weren't shown, I had accidentally named the file index.html.html, and so obviously it wasn't locating it.

However, now that my file extensions are showing, I am having this problem again (the last fiasco was about a week or two ago). I tried changing the contents of index.html again, just a simple text change, and it is still loading my previous page. I have tried restarting Apache through Administrative Tools > Services since the Apache and httpd commands in the command line won't work for me. I even tried deleting the index.html file and leaving htdocs empty and it's still displaying my old web page!!!

I have no idea why it's doing this and I can't find any other answers. I checked my DirectoryRoot and DirectoryIndex values and they all point to index.html (and plus, I haven't touched httpd.conf since installation anyways). Running Windows 8.1. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Windows has a feature that copies some files when non-administrator edit them. You see the changes, but the service doesn't.  Try editing your files as Administrator (not just someone with Administrator group privileges)